# php - create class with variable name

Tags: php, class, oop

I would like to create a php class by a variable name something like

```
$name = "class_name".time().mt_rand();
class $name {
    function function_one() {
        echo "LOL";
    }
}
$name::function_one();
```

I want an answer without using no eval.

Comment: If you give us some insight into why you would need this, we might be able to help you better. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was creating custom mvc framework and am trying to create a class by a filename.

Comment: Why would you need to _"create a class by a filename"_ and what does that actually mean? I've used plenty of MVC frameworks (including the ones I've built my self) and have never seen or needed this. Can you give some concrete example?

Comment: Let's say i am building user interface for it and i need to create classes by user inputs which are only associated with that user. Let alone creating am not even able to extend classes by variables.

Comment: That didn't really make it clearer. I mean, you would still need to define the properties and methods for the classes (since it otherwise would be kind of pointless), so why not just create a new instance of some already-defined class?

Comment: Seems like am choiceless. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Remember that each instance of an existing class can be unique.... if you only want the ability to access properties, then a StdClass would be perfectly normal; you'd probably only really need anonymous classes if you wanted different methods available.... there are use cases for anonymous classes, but I'm not convinced that this is one

Answer (score 2):

If you need to dynamically define classes, then use [Anonymous Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php), otherwise you should be giving your classes fixed names, not based on random variable values

```
$class = new class() {
    function function_one() {
        echo "LOL";
    }
};

$class->function_one();
```

But why do you need to use dynamically defined classes like this?

Comment: Great answer to a rather strange request. To add a little to it, he might even get his naming scheme working using variable variables, `$time = time(); $class{$time} = new class() {`

Comment: I was creating custom MVC frame works and am trying to avoid extending classes.

Comment: The code isn't working Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in

Comment: @iamnamrud What PHP-version are you using? Anonymous classes was introduced in PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks i just find out now am updating. I hope anything wouldn't mess when i update. Are there any depreciated PHP builtins?

Comment: @iamnamrud Google and you will find: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php